# how to go subPage in flutter Auto_router

Tags: flutter, auto-route

[I configured the main page using 'AutoTabsScaffold'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6emMj.png)

[And 'AppRouter' was designed in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJrAM.png)

[I want to go to the subpage like this, but it doesn't work. What should I do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdZEc.png)

I tried 'context.router.push ~', 'AutoRouter.of(context).push ~' but doesn't work ..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.